# Improve VBA flexibility to convert VLOOKUP to INDEX/MATCH

Tags: vba, excel

After all my searching for code to read in a VLOOKUP formula and converting it to INDEX/MATCH came up empty, I wrote some myself.

However, the code (below) is lacking some of the flexibility I would like, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work. Specifically, I would like to test each range criterion in the VLOOKUP formula for being an absolute reference or not, i.e. preceded by $, and carry that through to the INDEX/MATCH formula that results. For example, the formula `=VLOOKUP(A2,$A$1:B$11,2,FALSE)` should convert to `=INDEX(B$1:B$11,MATCH(A2,$A1:$A11,0))`.

NOTE: This sub depends on two functions (ColumnLetterToNumber and ColumnNumberToLetter). As their names imply they take column letters or numbers and interconvert them. Both these functions are short, simple, and work without problems. However, if anyone believes that the code to one or both of them would be helpful, I would be happy to provide them.

Additionally, any ideas on improving code readability and/or execution efficiency would also be appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ConvertToIndex()

Dim booLookupType As Boolean
Dim booLeftOfColon As Boolean
Dim booHasRowRef As Boolean
Dim lngStartCol As Long
Dim lngRefCol As Long
Dim lngStart As Long
Dim lngEnd As Long
Dim lngMatchType As Long
Dim lngInt As Long
Dim lngRowRef As Long
Dim strRefCol As String
Dim strOldFormula As String
Dim strNewFormula As String
Dim strLookupCell As String
Dim strValueCol As String
Dim strMatchCol As String
Dim strStartRow As String
Dim strEndRow As String
Dim strCheck As String
Dim strLookupRange As String
Dim strTabRef As String
Dim strSheetRef As String
Dim rngToMod As Range
Dim rngModCell As Range

Set rngToMod = Selection

For Each rngModCell In rngToMod
    strOldFormula = rngModCell.Formula
    lngStart = InStrRev(strOldFormula, "VLOOKUP(")
    If lngStart > 0 Then
        lngStart = InStr(lngStart, strOldFormula, "(") + 1
        lngEnd = InStr(lngStart, strOldFormula, ",")
        strLookupCell = Mid(strOldFormula, lngStart, lngEnd - lngStart)
        lngStart = lngEnd + 1
        lngEnd = InStr(lngStart, strOldFormula, ",")
        strLookupRange = Mid(strOldFormula, lngStart, lngEnd - lngStart)
        lngStart = lngEnd + 1
        lngEnd = InStr(lngStart, strOldFormula, ",")
        lngRefCol = CInt(Mid(strOldFormula, lngStart, lngEnd - lngStart))
        lngStart = lngEnd + 1
        lngEnd = InStr(lngStart, strOldFormula, ")")
        booLookupType = (Mid(strOldFormula, lngStart, lngEnd - lngStart) = "TRUE")
        If booLookupType Then
            lngMatchType = 1
        Else
            lngMatchType = 0
        End If
        booLeftOfColon = True
        lngEnd = InStr(1, strLookupRange, "]")
        If lngEnd > 0 Then
            strSheetRef = Left(strLookupRange, lngEnd)
            strLookupRange = Right(strLookupRange, Len(strLookupRange) - lngEnd)
        Else
            strSheetRef = ""
        End If
        lngEnd = InStr(1, strLookupRange, "!")
        If lngEnd > 0 Then
            strTabRef = Left(strLookupRange, lngEnd)
            strLookupRange = Right(strLookupRange, Len(strLookupRange) - lngEnd)
        Else
            strTabRef = ""
        End If
        For lngInt = 1 To Len(strLookupRange)
            strCheck = Mid(strLookupRange, lngInt, 1)
            Select Case True
                Case strCheck = ":"
                    booLeftOfColon = False
                Case booLeftOfColon
                    If IsNumeric(strCheck) Then
                        strStartRow = strStartRow & strCheck
                    Else
                        strMatchCol = strMatchCol & strCheck
                    End If
                Case Else
                    If IsNumeric(strCheck) Then strEndRow = strEndRow & strCheck
            End Select
        Next lngInt
        strMatchCol = Replace(strMatchCol, "$", "")
        lngStartCol = ColumnLetterToNumber(strMatchCol)
        strValueCol = ColumnNumberToLetter(lngStartCol + lngRefCol - 1)
        If Len(strStartRow) > 0 Then strStartRow = "$" & strStartRow
        If Len(strEndRow) > 0 Then strEndRow = "$" & strEndRow
        strValueCol = strSheetRef & strTabRef & strValueCol & strStartRow & ":" & strValueCol & strEndRow
        strMatchCol = strSheetRef & strTabRef & strMatchCol & strStartRow & ":" & strMatchCol & strEndRow
        strNewFormula = "=INDEX(" & strValueCol & ",MATCH(" & "$" & strLookupCell & "," & strMatchCol & "," & lngMatchType & "))"
        rngModCell.Formula = strNewFormula
    End If
Next rngModCell

End Sub
```

At this time I am not looking for help to take this to the next step of enabling it to process VLOOKUP/HLOOKUP or VLOOKUP/MATCH combination formulas.

Comment: First off, just by logic: `=VLOOKUP(A2,$A$1:B$11,2,FALSE)` should be converted to `=INDEX($B$1:B$11,MATCH(A2,$A$1:A$11,0))`! The range is absolute in rows for start an end and also for columns at the start, this also should be the case for your result. While this is not that problematic for your case, you will run in huge problems using more complex formulas. But still, without reading your sub I will try to write one on my own (because that looks tricky, I and I like such tasks) ;)

Comment: I don't quite understand. First you are eliminating in your code all `$` and now you want to carry them forward? So, why do you eliminate them in the first place? BTW, it seems that you are parsing with the above code through existing `VLookUp` formulas and try to dissect it into its pieces. Yet, this method does not seem to overcome the possibility of compounded formulas such as `=VLOOKUP(IF(G4=0,1,2),A1:B10,1,1)`.

Comment: @DirkReichel The key to the conversion example I gave is that in the VLOOKUP, there is no $ in front of B (allowing that range to be expanded), though obviously VLOOKUP is not conducive to dragging formulas, that is how some of my co-workers set up their VLOOKUPS to prepare for expanding ranges.

Comment: @Ralph I eliminate the $ because it was the most expedient solution to make it work without duplicating them in some instances, or adding them where I didn't want them. I am currently avoiding the possibility of compounded formulas because I only wrote this to work on formulas written by my co-workers, none of whom have demonstrated the use of complications such as  your example.

Comment: @PaaquaGrant you are right... while it doesn't make sense because it is going for column 2 anyways. To get the column, you need to go also for the parameter and not the range only. That said, you would need to cover the column to pick the value from not as a range directly but with `INDEX([full input range],[the match formula],[the part which points at the column])` so for your example it should look like `=INDEX($A$1:B$11,MATCH(A2,$A$1:$A$11,0),2)`... in that case, it also looks a bit easier, because there is no need to split the whole range multiple times.

Comment: makes sense if the column to pull from is set via `COLUMN()-2` or something like that... but then to clean up the formula, you would need to calculate it... at the other hand, if the column is given via `IF(A1=5,2,3)` it makes sense again to use the full range for index and just split it up for match...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid all errors I can think of, you would need to change it to a not so good looking way like this:

```
Sub changeToIndex()

  Dim xText As Boolean
  Dim xBrac As Long
  Dim VLSep As New Collection
  Dim i As Long, t As String

  With Selection.Cells(1, 1) 'just for now

    'it assumes that there is NEVER a text string which has VLOOKUP like =A1&"mean text with VLOOKUP inside it"
    While InStr(1, .Formula, "VLOOKUP", vbTextCompare)

      Set VLSep = New Collection
      VLSep.Add " " & InStr(1, .Formula, "VLOOKUP", vbTextCompare) + 7

      'get the parts
      For i = VLSep(1) + 1 To Len(.Formula)
        t = Mid(.Formula, i, 1)
        If t = """" Then
          xText = Not xText
        ElseIf Not xText Then 'avoid "(", ")" and "," inside of the string to be count

          If t = "(" Then
            xBrac = xBrac + 1
          ElseIf xBrac Then 'cover up if inside of other functions
            If t = ")" Then xBrac = xBrac - 1
          ElseIf t = ")" Then
            VLSep.Add " " & i
            Exit For
          ElseIf t = "," Then
            VLSep.Add " " & i 'the space is to avoid errors with index and item if both are numbers
          End If

        End If
      Next

      Dim xFind As String 'get all the parts
      Dim xRng As String
      Dim xCol As String
      Dim xType As String

      xFind = Mid(.Formula, VLSep(1) + 1, VLSep(2) - VLSep(1) - 1)
      xRng = Mid(.Formula, VLSep(2) + 1, VLSep(3) - VLSep(2) - 1)
      xCol = Mid(.Formula, VLSep(3) + 1, VLSep(4) - VLSep(3) - 1)
      If VLSep.Count = 5 Then
        xType = Mid(.Formula, VLSep(4) + 1, VLSep(5) - VLSep(4) - 1)
      Else
        xType = "0"
      End If

      Dim fullFormulaNew As String 'get the whole formulas
      Dim fullFormulaOld As String

      fullFormulaNew = "INDEX(" & xRng & ",MATCH(" & xFind & ",INDEX(" & xRng & ",,1)," & xType & ")," & xCol & ")"
      fullFormulaOld = Mid(Selection.Cells(1, 1).Formula, VLSep(1) - 7, VLSep(VLSep.Count) - VLSep(1) + 8)

      .Formula = Replace(.Formula, fullFormulaOld, fullFormulaNew) 'simply replace the old one with the new one
    Wend

  End With
End Sub
```

It also should work for very complex formulas. Still you would need some special checks to cut everything so it looks like you want. I just assumed that the range for the vlookup may be something like `IF(A1=1,B1:C10,L5:N30)` and this said, you would need additional subs to also clear something like this up. :(

A formula like

```
=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(IF(TRUE,A2,"aaa"),$A$1:B$11,2),$B$1:$C$11,2,FALSE)
```

will be changed (messed up) this way to

```
=INDEX($B$1:$C$11,MATCH(INDEX($A$1:B$11,MATCH(IF(TRUE,A2,"aaa"),INDEX($A$1:B$11,,1),0),2),INDEX($B$1:$C$11,,1),FALSE),2)
```

**EDIT**

Assuming your formulas are "normal" you can replace the the last part with:

```
      Dim xFind As String 'get all the parts
      Dim xRngI As String, xRngM As String
      Dim xCol As String
      Dim xType As String

      xFind = Mid(.Formula, VLSep(1) + 1, VLSep(2) - VLSep(1) - 1)
      xRngI = Mid(.Formula, VLSep(2) + 1, VLSep(3) - VLSep(2) - 1)
      xCol = Mid(.Formula, VLSep(3) + 1, VLSep(4) - VLSep(3) - 1)
      If VLSep.Count = 5 Then
        xType = Mid(.Formula, VLSep(4) + 1, VLSep(5) - VLSep(4) - 1)
      Else
        xType = "0"
      End If
      If xType = "FALSE" Then xType = 0

      Do While Not IsNumeric(xCol)
        Select Case MsgBox("Error: The Column to pick from is not numerical! Do you want to manually set the column (Yes) or directly use the last column of the input range (No)?", vbYesNoCancel)
        Case vbYes
          xCol = Application.InputBox("Input the column number for the input range (" & xRngI & "). '1' will be the range " & Range(xRngI).Columns(1).Address(0, 0) & ".", "Column to pick from", 1, , , , , 2)
        Case vbNo
          xCol = Range(xRngI).Columns.Count
        Case vbCancel
          xCol = " "
          Exit Do
        End Select
        If xCol <> CInt(xCol) Or xCol > Range(xRngI).Columns.Count Or xCol = 0 Then xCol = " "
      Loop

      If IsNumeric(xCol) Then

        Dim absRs As Boolean, absRe As Boolean, absCs As Boolean, absCe As Boolean

        absCs = (Left(xRngI, 1) = "$")
        absCe = (Mid(xRngI, InStr(xRngI, ":") + 1, 1) = "$")
        absRs = (InStr(2, Left(xRngI, InStr(xRngI, ":") - 1), "$") > 0)
        absRe = (InStr(Mid(xRngI, InStr(xRngI, ":") + 2), "$") > 0)

        xRngM = Range(xRngI).Columns(1).Cells(1, 1).Address(absRs, absCs) & ":" & Range(xRngI).Columns(1).Cells(Range(xRngI).Rows.Count, 1).Address(absRe, absCs) 'for MATCH
        xRngI = Range(xRngI).Cells(1, CLng(xCol)).Address(absRs, absCe) & ":" & Range(xRngI).Cells(Range(xRngI).Rows.Count, CLng(xCol)).Address(absRe, absCe) 'for INDEX

        Dim fullFormulaNew As String, fullFormulaOld As String

        fullFormulaNew = "INDEX(" & xRngI & ",MATCH(" & xFind & "," & xRngM & "," & xType & "))"
        fullFormulaOld = Mid(Selection.Cells(1, 1).Formula, VLSep(1) - 7, VLSep(VLSep.Count) - VLSep(1) + 8)

        .Formula = Replace(.Formula, fullFormulaOld, fullFormulaNew) 'simply replace the old one with the new one

      End If

    Wend

  End With
End Sub
```

As you can see: the "simpler" the outcome, the more code you need. If the `lookup_range` is not just a address, this will fail.

If you still have any questions, just ask ;)

Comment: I am not ungrateful, I simply haven't had a chance to implement it.  Also, it is far more complicated than I was looking for, considering I explicitly stated in my OP that I was NOT looking for a function to deal with overly complicated version of the VLOOKUP function. I did upvote the answer that Dirk Reichel provided, but because I don't have sufficient reputation, it doesn't display that upvote. I was holding out hope that someone could provide a simpler answer that more closely addressed the question I actually asked.

Comment: There is no reason to argue... up votes & accepts are just some points... and I don't care about them. Also not everyone is 24/7 acting at one problem. If the OP has a question, he can ask. And if that takes time, that is no problem. My answer was a bit more general, and right now it succeed all tests, but as said: it is not what the OP has asked for... I'll look into this again to provide something that matches the question a bit better ;)

Comment: @PaaquaGrant I edited my answer to get closer to what you want. Your example would be changed to `=INDEX(B$1:B$11,MATCH(A2,$A$1:$A$11,0))`. The only difference is that the rows for `MATCH` are absolute... but to my eyes that also makes more sense.